# Is it possible to get column id value, in another column.bound.format in Telerik grid, mvc3 and razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gridview, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have this code in my view:

```
columns.Bound(o => o.jobname).Width(100);
columns.Bound(o => o.objid)
     .Format(Ajax.ActionLink("delete", "QuotesDelete", new { id = "{0}" }, new { @class = "delete-link" })
     .ToHtmlString())
     .Encoded(false)
     .Title("");
```

Now I want to use the **jobname** column as an edit link, so I'm changing the jobname
to the following.

```
columns.Bound(o => o.jobname).Format(Ajax.ActionLink("{0}", "QuotesDetail", new { id = "is-it-possible-to-get-objid-value" })
         .ToHtmlString())
         .Encoded(false);
```

Is it possible to get the **objid** value in the *routeValues* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible if you need to use `Format`. Format is actually a shortcut to string.Format. If you want full access consider setting the template of the column (client or server). Here is an example:

```
columns.Bound(o => o.objid).Template(@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "QuotesDetail", new { id = @item.objid}));
```